# Artifacts when using Data Transfer modifier to fix bad shading on cylinder

Tags: modifiers, shaders, artifacts

[image]

I used the *Data Transfer* modifier to fix the bad shading on the cylinder. It has a complex geometry due to these small details. As a result I got such artifacts. I can't understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello maybe tell the shape you're trying to achieve?